# Avoiding a many-to-many relationship cycle between 3 tables

Tags: mysql, database-design, many-to-many

I'm designing a database for a IDLE CPU time donation system. and I struggled to design the database.

The problem is the following.
I have 3 entities (tables):

- donors: hold donors' information
- devices: a big array of various machine types (Phones, PCs, Tablets...)
- events: hold information about the events, that will receive the CPU donations.

The rules the database is based on are.

- Each donor owns many personal devices.
- A donor can register to events.
- By registering to an event, the donor choose which device(s) to donate CPU time from.
- A donor can register to as many events he chose to.
- A donor can register a device to multiple events.

At first, I created 2 additional tables besides the ones listed above(donors, devices, events):

- donor-device : this table contains the various devices (Phone, PC, TV ...) owned by clients.
- donor-event: this table contains the donors registered in events and the status of their participation (pending, rejected, accepted).

Then I discovered that this data model is not relevant in my use case. in this case I cannot know the devices that the donor chooses to donate for a specific event.

Here are some solutions I thought of, though I'm not convinced of their optimality.

- Adding a column in the **client-event** table containing a string with the id of the devices donated + the amount of CPU time donated.
- Using a JSON field instead if the string.
- Adding a third many-to-many relationship device-event-client.

PS: I'm not tied to a relational solution, I can try other models as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to solve your problem is to think of registrations as entities: a registration has a donor, an event, and a set of devices.

The relationship between donors and registrations has cardinality 1:N (a donor can have more registrations, a registration concerns a unique donor), the relationship between events and registrations has cardinality 1:N as well, while the relationship between registration and devices is M:N (in a registration, a donor can offer various devices, while a device can be registered multiple times for different events).

So, this situation can be represented with 5 tables:

```
Donors(DonorID, other attributes)
Devices(DeviceID, other attributes, OwnerID)
Events(EventID, other attributes)
Registrations(RegID, DonorID, EventID, maybe other attributes, like Status, Date, etc.)
RegistrationsDevices(RegID, DeviceID, maybe other attributes as TimeDonated, etc.)
```

with `DonorID` primary key for `Donors`, `DeviceID` primary key for `Devices`, `OwnerID`foreign key referring to a Donor, `EventID` primary key for `Events`, `RegID` primary key for `Registrations` (that has `DonorID` and `EventID` as foreign keys), and `(RegID, DeviceID)` primary key for `RegistrationsDevices` (and also foreign keys).

Comment: Thank you for you response. This quite what I was looking for except, I need the table `DonorsDevices` because I need to query devices owned by donors separately. for example many Donors can own a PC but the brand/CPU frequency and architecture can defer.
Should I just add a 6th table or is there a better way.

Comment: Can you solve this by adding to Devices a foreign key for Donors? In this case you can omit DonorID inside Registration (since this information is carried by DeviceID inside RegistrationsDevices).

Comment: Unfortunately, I'll have to the other way around. I think I'll have to add a foreign key for Devices in Donors.

Comment: In your question you said that each donor has several devices. So you can't put a foreign key in donor, otherwise you should have multiple value. Why can't you put a foreign key in device? A device can be shared by several donors?